# Navigation bar on top of page, content until 95% of page height

Tags: html, css

I have seen a lot of similar topics; however I do not seem to get the css code right.
Layout of my page:  has a background image. Then I want to create a white page in the middle with different blocks () starting with navigation at the top, header,content.

Im not getting the navigation bar to display at the top of the page (without space between the top of the browser and the bar) there is a small gap in between). Furthermore I want my content to always fill the screen until 'just' above the lower part of the browser.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href ="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="education.html">Education</a></li>
            <li><a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="more.html">More</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
    </div>

    <div class="maincontent">       
    </div>      
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url("bgimg.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
}
.wrapper{
width: 960px;
height: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
background-color: white;
}
.nav {
background-color: white;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
font-family: "Sans-serif", Verdana;
}
.nav li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
float: left;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
width: 20%;
line-height: 40px;
}
.nav a {
display: block;
width: 100px;
}
.header {
background-color: #F7D358;
width: 960px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
}
.maincontent {
background-color: white;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way in this case is to set:

```
.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I recommend you (highly) to use `CSS RESET STYLE` to avoid these problems.

Example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/